# Vue 2 app, pull down latest, getting error, workign for everyone else

Tags: vue.js, tfs

I've got a vue 2 project.

Other folks get latest in TFS and it works, only failing on my box

I deleted the old folder, force get currrent version, cd to src folder, Npm install, npm run serve

Get this error.

> 10 warnings found.  INFO  Starting development server...  ERROR
> Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc
> to be present in the dependency tree. Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue
> requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the
> dependency tree.
> at Object. (D:\TFS\StudentPortal4Vue_1_1\clientapp\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\compiler.js:14:15)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
> at Object. (D:\TFS\StudentPortal4Vue_1_1\clientapp\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js:8:20)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
> ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! student-portal@1.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service lint --fix && vue-cli-service serve --open` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm
> ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the student-portal@1.1.0 serve script. npm
> ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Brown.ericw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-07T18_01_49_062Z-debug.log

I compared the source, everything is the same, only the node folder is different

I got a copy of a coworkers local folder (Without node folders) working, did a compare by file looking for differences and testing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, we have packages-lock.json checked in to source contorl. If I delete that before the "npm install" everything works as expected.

Going to remove it from source control.